# C++: Operators and Templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, operators, operator-overloading

Following and example I took from another question, I understand why this does not work:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    Foo(int) {}
    Foo operator+(Foo const & R) { return Foo(); }
};


struct Bar {
    Bar() {}
    Bar(int) {}
};

Bar operator+(Bar const & L, Bar const & R) {
    return Bar();
}


int main() {
    Foo f;
    f+1;  // Will work - the int converts to Foo
    1+f;  // Won't work - no matching operator
    Bar b;
    b+1;  // Will work - the int converts to Bar
    1+b;  // Will work, the int converts to a Bar for use in operator+

}
```

But then, if I change it to use templates in this way:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    Foo(T) {}
    Foo operator+(Foo const & R) { return Foo(); }
};


template <class T>
struct Bar {
    Bar() {}
    Bar(T) {}
};

template <class T>
Bar operator+(Bar const & L, Bar const & R) {
    return Bar();
}


int main() {
    Foo<int> f;
    f+1;  // Will work - the int converts to Foo
    1+f;  // Won't work - no matching operator
    Bar<int> b;
    b+1;  // DOES NOT WORK
    1+b;  // DOES NOT WORK
```

}

It does not work. Can anyone put some light on this? Templates are driving me crazy.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not actually using `T` in your function template, so it is not automatically deducible (and wouldn't buy you anything here anyway). What are you actually trying to accomplish here, and why would it involve templates? This reads like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166663).

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems.

1. You need to add the template type to the arguments in the definition of the operator.  This is necessary because it needs to use them to know which instantiation of Bar to use.
2. If you want mixed operators (that operate on two separate types) in a template function, you're going to need to provide the definitions for all of the mixed cases.  Otherwise, the template deduction system won't work the way you want.

.

```
template <class T>
Bar<T> operator+(Bar<T> const & L, Bar<T> const & R) { // Fixed
    return Bar<T>();
}

template <class T>
Bar<T> operator+(Bar<T> const & L, const T & R) { // Added
    return L + Bar<T>(R);
}


template <class T>
Bar<T> operator+(const T& L, Bar<T> const & R) { // Added
    return Bar<T>(L) + R;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no implicit conversion between `int` and `Bar`, only between `int` and `Bar<int>`.  In fact, you haven't defined a type `Bar`; instead, you have a family of types `Bar<T>` for various values of `T`.  Probably you're seeing a compiler error connected to the definition of `operator+`, though it's likely hidden behind a thicket of other templated-type errors.

I don't have a c++ compiler in front of me, but I believe `template<class T> Bar<T> operator+(Bar<T> const & L, Bar<T> const & R)` will behave as you expect.

Comment: No, it will not works. http://liveworkspace.org/code/72de4f05c86bbd3127252956d89fe542

Comment: That's is what I was trying to do in the first place, I just forgot to change all the template. But if I do change it, it still does not behave the way I would like. So Dave S is right in is point 2.